# Why am I getting an import error in Replit using pyqt6

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am making a window in Replit and I am getting this error:

Libxkbcommon.so.0: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory.

This is my code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

 
import sys


app = QApplication(sys.argv)


window = QWidget()
window.show()  # IMPORTANT!!!!! Windows are hidden by default.

# Start the event loop.
app.exec()


# Your application won't reach here until you exit and the event
# loop has stopped.
```

I’ve tried pip installing Libxkbcommon but that didn’t stop the error. I tried running it on the  web browser on my windows 11 and it didn’t raise the error, unlike when I run the code on iOS Replit app